# matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation() adding unwanted color bars to seaborn.heatmap() on each refresh

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm trying to set up a running dashboard of `seaborn.heatmap()`s that will automatically refresh using `matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation()`.
Here's what a good - albeit mostly empty - visual should look like
[image: visual.]

Unfortunately, every time `FuncAnimation()` procs, more columns are added on the right side of the figure.

```
import datetime

from pyodbc import connect
from pandas import DataFrame
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

#settings up here
first_cycle = True

...

#create figure with subplots
fig,_ = plt.subplots(nrow,ncol)
fig.suptitle("Animated Heatmap(s)",fontsize=16)

#set subplot spacing
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.05, bottom=0.02, right=1.00, top=0.96, hspace=0.35, wspace=0.08)

#maximize screen
plt.get_current_fig_manager().window.state('zoomed')  #method works for Tk backend (default)

def load_figure(i, first_cycle):
    #subplot iterator
    for ax in fig.axes:
        plt.sca(ax)             #sets current axes
        plt.xticks(rotation=30)

    #get data from SQL Server
    cursor = connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}; \
                       SERVER=' + server + '; \
                       DATABASE=' + database + '; \
                       Trusted_Connection=yes;').cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT end_of_shift, item, value FROM SecretTableName " +
                       "WHERE end_of_shift BETWEEN '" + query_start_time + "' AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
    data_CT_DBout = cursor.fetchall()

    #create organized dataframes
    data_CT_ts = [nameShift( roundTime(item[0]) ) for item in data_CT_DBout]
    data_CT_item = [item[1] for item in data_CT_DBout]
    data_CT_val = [item[2] for item in data_CT_DBout]
    data_CT = DataFrame.from_dict({'Timestamp': data_CT_ts, 'CT': data_CT_item, 'Value': data_CT_val})

    #reshape data
    data_CT = data_CT.pivot(index = 'CT', columns = 'Timestamp', values = 'Value')
    data_CT.drop(drop_index_CT, inplace=True)
    data_CT.rename(index=rename_index_CT, inplace=True)

    #render as heatmap
    if first_cycle:
        graph_CT = sns.heatmap(data_SH01, annot=True, linewidths=0.5, vmax=14, vmin=8, ax = fig.axes[0], cmap=cmap, xticklabels=True, yticklabels=True)

    else:
        graph_SH01 = sns.heatmap(data_SH01, annot=True, linewidths=0.5, vmax=14, vmin=8, ax = fig.axes[0], cmap=cmap, xticklabels=True, yticklabels=True, cbar = False)


loop_animation = FuncAnimation(fig, load_figure, interval = refresh_setting * 1000, fargs=(first_cycle,))
plt.show()
```

The result of the above after a few refreshes is this: [image: Too many color bars]

If I add change the `#subplot iterator` to:

```
#subplot iterator
    for ax in fig.axes:
        ax.clear()
        plt.sca(ax)             #sets current axes
        plt.xticks(rotation=30)
```

the result becomes gives too many empty columns, as if it isn’t finding the heatmap. [image: result]

I also tried using `ax.remove()` within the `#subplot iterator`, but it didn't do what I intended it to do and I have been unable to recreate the result.

I am using `fig,_ = plt.subplots()` because the end goal is to have 5 of these heatmaps stacked vertically, but I am experiencing the same issue with even a single graph. I was able to use `fig,_ = plt.subplots()` with an animated scatter plot implementation of a similar project, but I would have no issue with changing it to fix the animation issue.

Any thoughts or solutions are appreciated.

Comment: You seem to have forgotter to update `first_cycle` in your animation loop (and you probably need to make it `global`)

Comment: That ```global``` seems to have done it. It turns out my understanding of global variables/passing arguments in Python was lacking. My initial program before I decontented for public viewing had a ```first_cycle = True``` towards the end, but trying again,  ```print(first_cycle)``` gave me only ```True```. Adding ```global first_cycle``` to the top fixed it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above code was not properly utilizing the `first_cycle` variable. In it, I tried to define the variable outside of the function and loop, and then pass the present value into the function to be run. After further testing, `print(first_cycle)` would never show `False` even when `first_cycle = False` was included in the function.

To make it work, the code should be rewritten as follows:

```
first_cycle = True

...

def load_figure(i):   #removed first_cycle argument
    global first_cycle   #added - be sure to use global variable

    ...

    #render as heatmap
    if first_cycle:
        graph_CT = sns.heatmap(data_SH01, ... )
        first_cycle = False   #be sure to turn off first_cycle

    else:
        graph_SH01 = sns.heatmap(data_SH01, ... , cbar = False)


loop_animation = FuncAnimation(fig, load_figure, interval = refresh_setting * 1000)   
#removed fargs argument
plt.show()
```